# Want to change app bar with other widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, appbar

Want to make blank app bar for one screen instead of app bar with logo title depending on the situation (mainly when using bottom navigation). But `appBar()` can't be replace with `container()` widget. How should I do?

Eg.. If bottom navigation bar Index become 0, app bar will disappear although for other Index app bar will appear.

Below is the code snippet with logo appbar

```
appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'assets/fblogosmall300.png',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 45,
        ),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  colors: <Color>[secondColor, mainColor])),
        ),
      ),
```

What I expected is, but completely get error.

```
appBar: currentIndex == 4? Container():AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'assets/fblogosmall300.png',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 45,
        ),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  colors: <Color>[secondColor, mainColor])),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Change Container to PreferredSizedWidget with its requirment size Size.fromheigth(100 or anything)

Comment: Yes. your answer is light for me. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the app bar just set the value at null.

```dart
appBar: currentIndex == 4 ? null : AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'assets/fblogosmall300.png',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 45,
        ),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  colors: <Color>[secondColor, mainColor])),
        ),
      ),
```

Or you can used PreferredSize widget like this

```dart
appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
        child: currentIndex == 4 ? Container() : AppBar(),
    ),
```

Comment: Yep, I used second way. I think that is more suitable way rather than set ```null```